# Using mysql query output as variable in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web, lamp

I am trying to use the output of an SQL query (in this case the output will be something like 26 "http://www.google.com"

I want to use the id and address in a process in php but cant seem to do anything with the output of the query other than echo it.

ultimately if i could end up with $id and $pos as variables that i could use that would be great.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("movieCol", $con);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `movie_collection` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
echo $row['id']. " ". $row['poster'];
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: [Please, don't use mysql_* functions in new code.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-function-in-php) They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) has begun on it. See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://uk3.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://uk1.php.net/mysqli) - this [article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which.

Comment: Please, don't use the `mysql_*` extension anymore: it's being deprecated. Look into `PDO` or `mysqli_*`

Comment: may i ask which **id and address in a process** ?

Comment: each row in the db has an id and a "poster" which is a url

Comment: @socialrel8, This [Link](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#function.mysql-connect-soft-deprecation-notice) will directly point to red box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign the values to variables as:
`$id=$row['id'];`
and
`$pos=$row['poster'];`

Now you can use the variables $id and $pos wherever you want.

I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: i have tried that and it didnt seem to work. From what i could find the variables from mysql are different to those from php and something needs to be done to turn a mysql variable into a php one

Comment: are the values from database echoed as they are? I mean to say are the values properly retrieved?

Comment: well now i can echo them separately ($id and &pos) but I cant use them outside of that capacity 

i would like to 

    copy('$pos', '$id.jpg'); but i dont think that is formatted correctly

Comment: i am not sure i followed 'cant use them outside of that capacity...'. Can u please elaborate?

Comment: when i try to use the new variables in anything other than a echo they dont work. Im currently trying to use the php copy() object and can do it with the actual values but not the variables

Comment: Try this. Take a new variable say, $target. So, $target=$id.'.jpg'; Now use this in copy($id,$target);

Comment: anyone tell you that you are genius lately? spot on!

Answer (score 0):

If you want them as separate variables then:

```
$query = "SELECT id, poster FROM `movie_collection` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1";

...

list($id, $pos) = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $id. " ". $pos;
```

Although functionally this won't be any more or less beneficial than using the array elements that you already had.

You could also use [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) which populates individual variables with the array elements:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
extract($row);
echo $id. " ". $pos . " " . $director; // access all variables
```

Extracting is not recommended though, there really is no benefit over using the array elements.

Comment: movie_collection
id
title
year
rated
released
genre
director
writer
actors
plot
poster
runtime
rating
votes
imdb
tstamp

Comment: sorry that didnt format well but its one table with a the various details about a movie all fields are default null except id which is auto increment

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to something like this?

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("movieCol", $con);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `movie_collection` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());

$whatYouWant = $row['id']. " ". $row['poster'];

mysql_close($con);
?><html>
<head><title><?=$whatYouWant?></title></head>
<body><h1><?=$whatYouWant?></h1></body></html>
```

All the warning about mysql_* being deprecated remain valid, of course. They become risky if your SQL contains anything that comes from outside the PHP script, like this:

**NEVER DO THIS:**

```
$value=$_REQUEST['item_id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM `movie_collection` WHERE `id`=$value DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Consider PDO or mysqli, etc.. as others have suggested (or at least remember to filter $value correctly every time).

Comment: thats perfect, i think im going nuts i swear that didnt work earlier. I will also be be tweaking to accommodate mysqli thanks!